# HTML 5 - download and run/execute a file

Tags: html, file, download, execute

Does HTML 5 provide a way to run or execute a downloaded file? I've read about the File API to download files but haven't seen mention of how to execute it.  It's probably frowned upon due to security concerns, but sometimes there's good reason to do this. To mitigate security issues, signed files could be required as a consideration for future enhancements of HTML5.

Comment: One would certainly hope not.

Comment: _'sometimes there's good reason to do this'_ - there is not, and won't be a reason to violate the security mechanisms.

Comment: Doesn't matter how good would be the intentions of such suggestion. Someone would find a way to pervert it and violate poor inocent machines.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to download and automatically execute a file with HTML5.